# What is a memory leak in structures? How can we rectify that?

Tags: c, structure

I have been asked in an Interview

> What is a memory leak in structures? How can we rectify that?

Can anyone help me in understanding Memory Leak in structure?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak

Comment: I thought its bit different than that of normal memory leaks

Answer (score 6):

I guess the obvious answers would be that a leak in a structure is when a pointer that points to allocated memory resides in the structure and the structure goes out of scope before the memory pointed at by its member is freed.  It would be rectified by freeing any memory that is pointed to from inside the structure before freeing (or letting go out of scope) the structure.

Pretty sure that's what the question was asking... :)

Answer (score 1):

The important point to remember is:

**Dynamic memory is always allocated as well as deallocated explicitly.**

Anytime you allocate a memory to a pointer by using `malloc` and do not explicitly call `free` on the same pointer/passing same address to `free` it results in a memory leak

In case of structures, whenever you have a pointer member which is allocated dynamic memory using `malloc` then it should be explicitly `free`d by calling `free` failing to do so results in memory leak.

**[An Code Example:](http://ideone.com/LU1Ho)**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct MyStruct
{
    char *str;
    int i;
};

int main()
{
   struct MyStruct *ptr = (struct MyStruct *)malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
   ptr->i = 10;
   /*str is allocated dynamic memory*/
   ptr->str = malloc(10);

   strncpy(ptr->str,"Hello",6);

   printf("[%d]",ptr->i);
   printf("[%s]",ptr->str);


   /*Frees memory allocated to structure*/    
   /*But Oops you didn't free memory allocated to str*/
   /*Results in memory leak*/
   //free(ptr);

   /*Correct order of deallocation*/
   /*free member memory*/
   free(ptr->str);
   /*free structure memory*/
   free(ptr);


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know you're only trying to be clear to the OP, but the explicitly part is wrong. For instance, a lot of libraries malloc memory, and require the "client" to free that memory. Some collections might automatically free elements, or RAII tactics used (requiring no explicit call to free). And it's quite straight forward to use C with a conservative garbage collector, where free isn't being explicitly called.

Comment: @Heptic: Explicitly part is very much correct unless mentioned otherwise by any api or datastructure one uses.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [Dynamic memory allocation in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

The common errors that occurs during dynamic memory allocation/free are as follows [which are explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation#Common_errors)]

The improper use of dynamic memory allocation can frequently be a source of bugs.

Most common errors are as follows:

- **Allocation failure:** Memory allocation is not guaranteed to succeed. If there's no check for successful allocation implemented, this usually leads to a crash of the program or the entire system.
- **Memory leaks:** Failure to deallocate memory using `free` leads to buildup of memory that is non-reusable memory, which is no longer used by the program. This wastes memory resources and can lead to allocation failures when these resources are exhausted.
- **Logical errors:** All allocations must follow the same pattern: allocation using `malloc`, usage to store data, deallocation using `free`. Failures to adhere to this pattern, such as memory usage after a call to free or before a call to `malloc`, calling `free` twice, etc., usually leads to a crash of the program.

The above mentioned is applicable to `structures` and also to other constructs of `C`.

Hope this helps!